# How to include a While statement in this code

Tags: c++

I am working with a small code on **C++**, I've manage to ask for the user input for a desired number of the sequence to run as the below example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 1;
    int i = 0;
    int num = 0;
    printf("How many times you want the sequence to run: \n");
    scanf ("%d",&num);
    for (i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        printf ("%d \n",x);
        x = x + y;
        y = x - y;
    }
    getchar ();
    return 0;
}
```

My question is how to make it go back to ask the user if another number of sequence wants to be run or just exit from the application. I am aware of the use of the `while` or `do while` in order to create a loop in these however I am unsure on where to add it in my code.
thanks for any feedback

Comment: You will need to use a `while` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using an infinite while loop as recommended above, I would instead have there be a do-while loop that checks the user input. This would look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    char input;
    do{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 1;
    int i = 0;
    int num = 0;
    printf("How many times you want the sequence to run: \n");
    scanf ("%d",&num);
    for (i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        printf ("%d \n",x);
        x = x + y;
        y = x - y;
    }


    printf("Press R to run another sequence or any other key to quit.\n");
    scanf ("%c",&input);
    }while(input == 'r');

    return 0;
}
```

You should try to avoid infinite while loops in your code, and for Fibonacci numbers, a recursive function is much better and is designed for this kind of application.

Comment: your suggestion worked like charm, just needed to change the scanf("%i") to scanf (" %c")

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your code into a `while` loop.

One solution:

```
while(1)
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 1;
    int i = 0;
    int num = 0;
    printf("How many times you want the sequence to run: \n");
    printf("To quit input any character that isn't a number \n");

    if (scanf ("%d",&num) != 1) break;  // Stop if the user doesn't input a valid number

    for (i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        printf ("%d \n",x);
        x = x + y;
        y = x - y;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, I did tried it and made some slight changes and it worked as It was intended, will use it in future references. 
P.S: I still don't understand the number of downvotes, guess I will need to improve on what asking and answering.

Comment: @HasanPatel Regarding the downvotes... Well I can't know why your question was downvoted 4 times. One reason could be that you used too many tags. You added both C and C++ but specifically write that it's C++. So why add a C tag? Further you added a Fibonacci tag but your question wasn't about Fibonacci at all so no need for that tag. So for future questions make sure only to add the relevant tag.

Answer (score 0):

Using some of the feedback provided manage to do the trick; here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    char input;
    do{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 1;
    int i = 0;
    int num = 0;
    printf("How many times you want the sequence to run: \n");
    scanf ("%d",&num);
    for (i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        printf ("%d \n",x);
        x = x + y;
        y = x - y;
    }

    printf("Press R to run another sequence or any other key to quit.\n");
    scanf (" %c",&input);
}
    while(input == 'r');

    return 0;
}
```

using the `scanf (" %c", &input);` was able to read the declared variable `char input;` to make the `do` and `while` loop work in the code.